# SQL Queries with multiple words

Tags: mysql

Is there a way to query mysql to determine if 2 words are present, regardless of order?

Such as:

```
select * from 'table' where 'column1' LIKE ('word1' AND column1 LIKE 'word2')
```

I would like it to return results if both words are in the column, regardless which word comes first.  To complicate things, I want to run this on each column in table.

```
select * from 'table' where 'column1' LIKE ('word1' AND 'word2')
        OR 'column2' like ('word1' AND 'word') etc
```

Newbie to SQL.  Thanks for any and all help!

This is what I tried:

```
$sql = "select * from units where name like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR unit like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR address like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR home like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR cell like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR work like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR office like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR fax like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR email like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR specialties like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR agency like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR keywords like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR misc1 like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')
OR misc2 like ('%$searchwords[0]%' AND '%$searchwords[1]%')";
```

I have an if statement to return results with 1 word or mulitple.  Single word works fine, multiple does not.

Comment: Disregard, figured it out!   select * from units where name like '%$searchwords[0]%' AND name like '%$searchwords[1]%'

Comment: make sure to fix your sql injection vulnerabilities with prepared statements instead of string interpolations

Comment: @erik258  Complete amateur here, can you elaborate please?  This function is contained in a separate password protected directory.  Its called from a different location.  Is this what you mean?

Comment: Read https://www.php.net/manual/en/security.database.sql-injection.php

Comment: *Disregard, figured it out!* It is possible for you to answer your own question - and accept that answer. Then we know that question has an answer and other users can benefit.